# Testing code that produces Datomic transaction data

Tags: testing, clojure, transactions, datomic

I have written some code in Clojure that produces Datomic transaction data, and I'd like to write some tests to check that the data is created as expected.

Essentially, I need to be able to demonstrate that with respect to transaction data:

```
[{:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user)
  :some-field "Bob"}]

=

[{:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user)
  :some-field "Bob"}]
```

and

```
[{:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user)
  :ref-field (d/tempid :db.part/user -1)}
 {:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user)
  :ref-field (d/tempid :db.part/user -1)}]

=

[{:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user)
  :ref-field (d/tempid :db.part/user -2)}
 {:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user)
  :ref-field (d/tempid :db.part/user -2)}]
```

but

```
[{:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user -1)
  :some-field "Bob"}]

!= 

[{:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user -2)
  :some-field "Bob"}]
```

However, I cannot simply compare the output with an expected value as I will never know the exact DbId created until it's produced by the code, and the result is different every time (d/tempid ...) is called anyway. So equality checks will return false.

Does anyone have any thoughts for the best way to do this in a general way, so it can be run against any sort of transaction data (e.g. works with nested transaction data)?

I have considered creating my own MockDbId type with an overridden equals method, and then redefining (d/tempid ...) in tests to return this mock id, but it doesn't feel like a good way to achieve the desired behaviour.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Matt.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using the `wild-match?` function [from the Tupelo library.](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#fast--simple-wild-card-matches)

Samples:

```
(wild-match?  {:a :* :b 2}
              {:a 1  :b 2})         ;=> true

(wild-match?  [1 :* 3]
              [1 2  3]
              [1 9  3] ))           ;=> true

(wild-match?  {:a :*       :b 2}
              {:a [1 2 3]  :b 2})   ;=> true
```

In your case, replace `:a` with `:db/id`

If you wish to do deeper inspection of the transaction result, you can use the `tx-datoms` function.  Here is an example [from the unit test:](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo-datomic/blob/master/test/tst/tupelo_datomic/bond.clj#L266)

```
  ; Create Honey Rider and add her to the :people partition
  (let [tx-result   @(td/transact *conn* 
                        (td/new-entity :people ; <- partition is first arg (optional) to td/new-entity 
                          { :person/name "Honey Rider" :location "Caribbean" :weapon/type #{:weapon/knife} } ))

        tx-datoms   (td/tx-datoms (live-db) tx-result)
  ]
    ; tx-datoms looks like:
    ;    [ {:e 13194139534328,
    ;       :a :db/txInstant,
    ;       :v #inst "2016-10-02T21:45:44.689-00:00",
    ;       :tx 13194139534328,
    ;       :added true}
    ;      {:e 299067162756089,
    ;       :a :person/name,
    ;       :v "Honey Rider",
    ;       :tx 13194139534328,
    ;       :added true}
    ;      {:e 299067162756089,
    ;       :a :location,
    ;       :v "Caribbean",
    ;       :tx 13194139534328,
    ;       :added true}
    ;      {:e 299067162756089,
    ;       :a :weapon/type,
    ;       :v 17592186045419,
    ;       :tx 13194139534328,
    ;       :added true} ]
    (is (= "Honey Rider" (:v (only (keep-if #(= :person/name  (:a %)) tx-datoms)))))
    (is (= "Caribbean"   (:v (only (keep-if #(= :location     (:a %)) tx-datoms)))))
    (is (= 1                (count (keep-if #(= :weapon/type  (:a %)) tx-datoms))))
    (is (= 1                (count (keep-if #(= :db/txInstant (:a %)) tx-datoms))))
    (is (apply = (map :tx tx-datoms)))  ; All datoms have the same :tx value
 )
```

So you don't know in advance what the `:e` or `:tx` values will be, but you can check for equality if you really need to (see last test).

Comment: Hi Alan - Thanks for the reply. Your solution works fine for the first code block in my example but does not give me the functionality I require for the other parts. in the second block for example, I cannot entirely ignore the values as I need to verify that the temp id in the first map is the same as in the second. It is not possible to do this with a wildcard.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how you can check the post-transaction values, although I'm not sure what the use-case is for this.